# How to set title from page-template?

Tags: page-template

We store the data for the user profiles on our site in a mongodb and provide them via a REST API. So i added a page template page-profile.php. In that file we call the REST API and fill the template with the responding data. We added rewrite_rules to the functions.php, so the profile template knows which profile fetch from the REST API.

**functions.php**

```
add_rewrite_rule('^termin/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$',
                 'index.php?pagename=profile&location=$matches[1]&industry=$matches[2]&slug=$matches[3]',
                 'top');
```

**page-profile.php**

```
$slug = $location = htmlspecialchars(urldecode(get_query_var('slug')));
$office = $dataAccess->getProfile($slug);
```

That all works fine, we use the `$slug` to get the correct data from the REST API and store them in the `$office` variable. `$office->name` describe the name of the profile. My question is: How can i use the `$office->name` in the page title (needed for better SEO)?

I know I can use the the wordpress filter `wp_title` to set the title dynamically in the functions.php. But how I can use the `$office->name` (page-profile.php) in the `wp_title` filter (functions.php)?

Comment: When is `$dataAccess` initialized?

Comment: in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `$dataAccess` is instantiated as a `global`. If that is true, this code...

```
$slug = $location = htmlspecialchars(urldecode(get_query_var('slug')));
$office = $dataAccess->getProfile($slug);
```

... should also work in a `wp_title` callback. You'd just need `global $dataAccess;` to pull the variable into scope, though there are probably more elegant ways to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the long time i didnt write something. The problem is, that the page-profile.php will be executed later than the functions.php. So i never can get the value, without calling the database twice with the $dataAccess object.